# flextable in RMarkdown PDF without making an image if possible

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, flextable

I am working to help some colleagues update some reports that they have to do a lot of manual work for and trying to update their flow with RMarkdown to automate their work.

I was able to use flextable to recreate the tables they want in an ideal state.

However, when I work to export the table to PDF, I am unable to get it to adjust appropriately to fit on the page in a clear manner.
I am trying to avoid making it an image first in the process but will explore that next, if necessary.

Here is the original table:
[image: Table from example work]

Packages (some are for the general work and can be ignored since this is just the table work):

````
``` {r setup, include = FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(labelled)
library(tidyr)
library(flextable)
library(lubridate)

```
````

Output I'm replicating ( this looks to be a pretty close match in the Viewer):

````
```{r data, echo = FALSE}
t11a <-structure(list(name = c("Your race, ethnicity or national origin", 
"Your race, ethnicity or national origin", "Your race, ethnicity or national origin", 
"Your race, ethnicity or national origin", "Your race, ethnicity or national origin", 
"Your religion", "Your religion", "Your religion", "Your religion", 
"Your religion", "Your sex or gender (being male, female, transgender, genderqueer, genderfluid)^", 
"Your sex or gender (being male, female, transgender, genderqueer, genderfluid)^", 
"Your sex or gender (being male, female, transgender, genderqueer, genderfluid)^", 
"Your sex or gender (being male, female, transgender, genderqueer, genderfluid)^", 
"Your sex or gender (being male, female, transgender, genderqueer, genderfluid)^", 
"Your gender expression (your style, dress, or the way you walk or talk)*", 
"Your gender expression (your style, dress, or the way you walk or talk)*", 
"Your gender expression (your style, dress, or the way you walk or talk)*", 
"Your gender expression (your style, dress, or the way you walk or talk)*", 
"Your gender expression (your style, dress, or the way you walk or talk)*"
), val = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("Never", 
"Once or twice", "About once a week", "Several times a week", 
"Every day"), class = "factor"), `Grade_5th_Male_%` = c("89%", 
"7%", "1%", "1%", "1%", "90%", "5%", "2%", "1%", "2%", "90%", 
"6%", "1%", "1%", "2%", "", "", "", "", ""), `Grade_5th_Female_%` = c("90%", 
"7%", "1%", "1%", "1%", "90%", "8%", "1%", "0%", "1%", "80%", 
"14%", "1%", "1%", "3%", "", "", "", "", ""), `Grade_8th_Male_%` = c("85%", 
"9%", "2%", "2%", "2%", "93%", "4%", "1%", "1%", "1%", "96%", 
"2%", "1%", "0%", "1%", "87%", "9%", "2%", "1%", "1%"), `Grade_8th_Female_%` = c("83%", 
"14%", "3%", "1%", "0%", "90%", "7%", "2%", "1%", "0%", "86%", 
"10%", "2%", "2%", "1%", "73%", "19%", "5%", "2%", "2%"), `Grade_9th_Male_%` = c("87%", 
"8%", "3%", "1%", "1%", "93%", "5%", "1%", "1%", "1%", "96%", 
"3%", "1%", "0%", "0%", "90%", "7%", "1%", "1%", "1%"), `Grade_9th_Female_%` = c("84%", 
"11%", "2%", "2%", "1%", "91%", "6%", "1%", "1%", "0%", "88%", 
"8%", "3%", "1%", "1%", "78%", "15%", "4%", "2%", "1%"), `Grade_11th_Male_%` = c("87%", 
"9%", "2%", "1%", "1%", "95%", "3%", "1%", "0%", "0%", "95%", 
"3%", "1%", "0%", "0%", "88%", "8%", "2%", "1%", "1%"), `Grade_11th_Female_%` = c("88%", 
"9%", "2%", "1%", "0%", "92%", "6%", "1%", "1%", "0%", "89%", 
"8%", "2%", "1%", "0%", "83%", "12%", "3%", "1%", "0%")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```{r qt11, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warnings = FALSE,  results = "asis", fig.pos = '!h'}
t11a1 <- flextable(t11a) |> 
  separate_header() |> #this takes that header and makes it into several levels based on how things repeat
  align(align = c("left", "left", rep("center", 8)), part = "header") |> #set up alignment for header
  align(align = c("left", "left", rep("center", 8)), part = "body") |>  #match alignment with body
  merge_v(j = ~ name) |> #merge the row names into one if repeat
  valign(j = "name", valign = "top", part = "body") |> # move the alignment to the top of the cell for merged cells
  width(j = "name", width = 1.7) |> #set the width of the first column
  width(j = "val", width = 1.25) |> #set the width of the first column
  bold(bold = TRUE, part = "header") |> #bold the header
  bold(j = c(1,2), bold = TRUE, part = "body") |> #bold the first and second column of the body
  height(height = 1.5) |>
  fontsize(size = 9, part = "body") |> 
  fontsize(size = 9, part = "header") |> 
  fontsize(size = 8, part = "footer") |> 
  border_inner(part = "all", border = fp_border(color = "black", width = .5)) |> #set the inner border
  border_outer(part = "all", border = fp_border(color = "grey50", width = 2)) |> # set the outer border
  fix_border_issues() |> # the borders don't appear appropriately in the viewer sometimes, so this cleans this up
  add_footer_lines(values = c("* 5th grade surveys did not ask this question.", # add your footnotes
  '^ Change in question wording from 2019; 5th grade survey item was worded "Your gender (being male or female)".')) |> 
    compose(j = c("name", "val"), part = "header", value = as_paragraph("During the last 30 days, how often have other students harassed or bullied you for any of the following reasons?")) |> # rename name and val to the name of the variable to merge into one field
  merge_h(i = c(1,2), part = "header") |>    # merge header slot one and two together
  set_table_properties(opts_pdf = list(arraystretch = 3.5))

t11a1 
```
````

What it looks like when I try to push out PDF:
[image: Table as shown in pdf]

I've looked around without much luck, so hoping I can get some assistance here.